# Asp .Net Grid with several controls in row then How to perform Insert, update and delete operation simultaneously in single button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have one asp .net grid with controls in row and I want to perform Insert, Update and delete operation based on user input and click on save button it will modify the database table with sql server.

Means all crud operation in single database request according to the user input.

Comment: Where is your code? This question is too general.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show what you have tried and what problem you are having. And anyway, why would you want to *"perform insert, update and delete operation simultaneously"*?

Comment: My question is like similar to topic mentioned in this link https://contrivedexample.com/2017/05/27/c-data-binding-example-with-adapters-and-datagridview/ and in my case one column of delete button also there so I insert one row, update two row and delete one all this done by clicking on save button. in above link code is vb but i want it in C#